# uncaught referenceerror: is not defined onclick AspNet MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my project I need to call a "Save Items" function, but when I click the button nothing happens .. and I get the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: SaveData is not defined
     At HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Create: 82) "
Anyone have any idea what might be causing this error?

The function:

```
function SalvarPedido() {

var data = $("#Data").val();
var valor = $("#Valor").val();
var descricao = $("#Descricao").val();

var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Pedido/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

var headers = {};
var headersadr = {};
headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;
headersadr["__RequestVerificationToken"] = tokenadr;


var url = "/Pedido/Create";

$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "json"
    , headers: headersadr
    , data: { Id: 0, Data: data, Valor: valor, Descricao: descricao, __RequestVerificationToken: token }
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.Resultado > 0) {
            ListarItens(data.Resultado);
        }
    }

});
```

}

The HTML:

```
div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

            <a href="#" onclick="SalvarPedido();"class="btn btn-default">Salvar Pedido</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you referencing the script file?

Comment: @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/Pedido.js"></script>
}

Comment: Where is your SaveData method?

Comment: I'm assuming that your "SaveData" error message has been tinkered with by you? because there is no SaveData defined in this script.  Is that what the error reads verbatim?